# Getting error while calling a web service

Tags: java, web-services, service, web

I'm trying to call a web service in Java I've made but I keep getting an error, here's my code:

```java
System.out.print("web service call: ......");
try{
    String text = webFunction(text);
    System.out.println(" OK");
    System.out.println("web answer: "+texto);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(" Error\nError code: "+e);
}
```

And the error I get is:

```
Error code: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Index: 29, Size: 29
```

If anyone could tell me what does the error means, or, maybe tell me how to solve it it'll be great.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code? What libraries are you using to make the client? More info please..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a array/ list out of bound issue. You are trying to retrieve item index 29 but the maximal index is 28. Check your while loops / for loops